# find the longest list of intervals so that each interval contains all the subsequents

Tags: sorting

This is a homework. I'm pretty sure that I should use a sorting or some sort of binary tree, but I can not do it. I'm writing this after 3 days of struggle : /

I have N intervals. Given two intervals [a, b] and [c, d] we will say that the first contains the second if a < c and d < b. Create an O(N * log N) algorithm to find the longest list of intervals such that every interval contains all the intervals following it.

Comment: I've told you - I haven't came up with anything. I can think of many algs that solve this in O(N*N) time but nothing using sorting. I tried to brute force the solution, by applying different standard approaches - sort by start time, sort by end time... greedy approach after sorting by end time, etc.